# How to Return a Text with an Image in Laravel 4

Tags: php, image, laravel, intervention

I'm working on a Laravel 4 application and I wrote a method called `show()` inside my controller that gets the `id` from the route and makes an array of some elements from the database, these elements will be returned with an image. 
I can return the image without the text using `Response::make()` and a header, but if I bind it with a data it can't read the image.

I tried to do something like :

```
public function show($id){

    $onlineAd = OnlineAds::where('id', $id)->get(array('title', 'short_description', 'full_description'));

    $fileName = OnlineAds::find($id)->image;
    $path = 'app/storage/uploads/mobile/' . $fileName;

    return Response::json([
        "data" => $onlineAd,

        "Image"=> base64_encode(File::get($path))
    ]);
}
```

This returns the data perfectly, but the image returns as an unreadable text instead. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: can you post the relevant bit of code that displays or handles the displaying of the image?

Comment: @AlexAndrei it is above, here it is again 

   return Response::json([
        "data" => $onlineAd,

        "Image"=> base64_encode(File::get($path))
    ]);

Answer (score 0):

I assume you don't do this already in the view, this is what I meant by the "code that handles the displaying of the image"

Before inserting it in the `src` attribute, you should format the image payload properly.
Change this bit of code like so:

```
return Response::json([
    "data" => $onlineAd,

    "Image"=> 'data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode(File::get($path))
]);
```

to include the `data` and the `mime type` and the `base64` after the comma.

Modify the `mime type` accordingly, `image/png`, `image/jpg`, etc.

Also, see this for reference [How to display Base64 images in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499633/how-to-display-base64-images-in-html)

Comment: that didn't change the output, even a bit. it still giving me unreadable text instead of an image

Comment: check the `base64` string to see if it's valid or not, then check the answers on the reference question I posted. If you could edit your post with the part from the view, that would be great too :)

Comment: another thing you could do is do a view source on the document and post what is actually displayed

Comment: and by view you mean the output I'm receiving when running the code? or you mean the view file ?

Comment: I mean both. The relevant part of the view file, where you display the image *and* the output you get.

Comment: I tried to use a bit of an html code to display the image but it returns a blank page, the code looks like this echo ('<img src="',$src,'">';). 

I don't have a view as I'm working as a backend developer, that's why I don't use a view to output the data. For the output, it gives  large number of texts, so I can't post it all here. It starts with------- ({"data":[{"title":"title","short_description":"this is short","full_description":"this is full "}],"Image":"data:image\/file;base64,\

Comment: you can use pastebin or any other alternative to post the entire output. One thing that comes up is the `mime type` of `image/file` try to use `image/jpg` or whatever type of image you have

Comment: also your `echo` statement looks wrong. You have some commas there that shouldn't be there. Modify it like this: `echo '<img src="' . $src . '" />';` and please post also how `$src` gets populated.

Comment: echo  '<img src="' . $path . '" />'; gives a blank page

Comment: I provided an answer below, please look it up

Answer (score 0):

I successfully made the desired output, but still not sure if this is the best way to display a text alongside an image,

here is my code :

```
    $fileName = OnlineAds::find($id)->image;
    $path = 'app/storage/uploads/mobile/' . $fileName;
    $data=base64_encode(file_get_contents($path));
    $src= 'data: '.mime_content_type($path).';base64,'.$data;


    echo '<img src="' . $src . '" />';

    return Response::json([
        "data" => $onlineAd,

    ]);
```

So, I echoed the image and returned the text, if you have a better solution that returns both of them without the echo statement then don't hesitate to provide it.